# QEGLPlatformContext::makeCurrent:eglError

Tags: qt

I am working on `Qt Quick [camera] application` in jetson board. When I am launching and selecting camera from combobox for streaming in the application, It is throwing error

> "QEGLPlatformContext::makeCurrent: eglError: 3009, this: 0x67d4d0"

Please help to fix this issue.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem on my Jetson and made some investigation. Probably it had the same origin as yours. QEGLPlatformContext is always created with only support of EGL Window surfaces although its subclasses (at least QEGLXcbPlatformContext) may also use a EGL PBuffer surface. And actually this result in 3009 (EGL_BAD_MATCH) error when you try to bind the context with an offscreen (pbuffer) surface.

I've filed a [bug](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-53023) where you can find the description of a dirty fix which helped me. It might help you also. On Ubuntu QEGLPlatformContext and QEGLPbuffer classes are part of libqt5gui5 package. Good luck!